# statistics's resources in Windows servers

Tags: windows

I have a few Windows servers doing "dummy" tasks.

I want to move these to a ESXi Server. But in order to do this, I want to know how much resources allocate to each vm.
Which Software (free or not) can I use to make this reports?

Answer (score 0):

http://h71019.www7.hp.com/activeanswers/cache/120132-0-0-0-121.html